# CardView cardElevation draws random square inside of CardView

Tags: java, android, android-cardview, cardview

A simple problem, I used a `CardView` to add elevation to a Button but when assigning `cardElevation` , then the `CardView` draws a box inside of itself, I tried switching the elevation and other attributes and I can minimize the effect of it by increasing the `cardElevation` but that is not a solution.

Here is the `CardView` from the XML.

```
  <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="38sp"
            android:layout_height="38sp"
            app:cardElevation="5sp"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:layout_marginTop="60sp"
            android:layout_marginRight="12sp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="12sp"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="#97FFFFFF"></androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

The `CardView` in the app. (The box in the upper right corner)

[image]

The whole XML file, the last `CardView` is the one on the image.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.flipboard.bottomsheet.BottomSheetLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottomsheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.map.MapFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardElevation="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="#97FFFFFF">

      <ImageButton
          android:layout_width="38dp"
          android:layout_height="38dp"
          android:padding="1dp"
          android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_refresh_24"
          android:background="#00FFFFFF"
          android:elevation="10dp"
          android:id="@+id/btn_reset_map"/>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
        
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:cardElevation="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="#97FFFFFF">

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="38dp"
                android:layout_height="38dp"
                android:padding="1dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_layers_24"
                android:background="#00FFFFFF"
                android:elevation="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/btn_layer_map"/>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="38dp"
            android:layout_height="38dp"
            app:cardElevation="5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="#97FFFFFF"></androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    </LinearLayout>
</fragment>

</com.flipboard.bottomsheet.BottomSheetLayout>
```

Comment: Why all of your unit in sp? 
Did you try changing them to dp?

Comment: I've been using sp for no specific reason, now I read that sp is rather for the size of fonts and dp for all else. Having now tried it with dp as well, nothing changed, the square is still there.

Comment: I wonder, how your xml is structured. What is the parent of cardview?
Is it possible to share all code of the layout where that particular cardview is in?

Comment: I added the xml file at the end of my question, the last CardView is the one displayed on the image.

Comment: Why are you using a fragment tag as a view group?

Comment: At first the map xml was created as a Fragment and I have not changed it. My knowledge on some concepts are lacking and I am not sure how to add the buttons and other parts into this layout so that they would be on top of the <Fragment> containing the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `CardView` background color programmatically to the same color as the color set with `app:cardBackgroundColor`

```
CardView cardview = findViewById(R.id.cardview);
cardview.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.cardview_color));
```

And create this color in colors.xml

```
<color name="cardview_color">#97FFFFFF</color>
```

And add this id to the xml:

```
  <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
      android:id="@+id/cardview"
      ....
```

Note: For some reason `android:background="#97FFFFFF"` doesn't work

Comment: The square inside the CardView issue is now fixed though it removed the cardCornerRadius and I can't seem to add that now. Also as an addition, if I have more CardViews, should each of these have the background color set in the same way?

Comment: @EdwardAarma You're right .. let me think of it

Comment: @EdwardAarma I guess you need to remove the opacity of the `app:cardBackgroundColor` color, this is the reason you see the inner square .. So you can set it like `app:cardBackgroundColor="#EDEDED"` This will make it opaque.. and cancel using `setBackgroundColor` that mentioned in the answer

Answer (score 1):

Setting `android:outlineProvider="none"` fixed the issue for me